# How to always generate data for optional keys in a spec?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec, test.check

If I have a spec like

```
(clojure.spec/def ::person (clojure.spec/keys :req [::name ::address] :opt [::age]))
```

And when I do

```
(clojure.spec.gen/generate (clojure.spec/gen ::person))
```

Is there any way to tell the generator to always consider the optional key(s) when generating data for it?

I know that this could be done with custom generators but I wanted to know if there is a functionality already available for it or maybe a simpler approach which does not involve me defining a custom generator.

Comment: You want *all* generated values to have *all* optional keys? What is your use case? I would be surprised if there was a flag for that.

Comment: Yes, whatever values are generated, should have all the keys (including optional).

Comment: If _all_ the generated values should contain the optional keys, well, then the keys are not optional :-) Or said in another way: they would not test the code path that deals with optional keys not being present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was to walk through the form (using `clojure.spec.alpha/form`) of that spec, merge optional keys into required keys if the spec was created using `clojure.spec.alpha/keys` and finally regenerate the spec.

```
(defn merge-opt-keys
  "Merges optional keys into requried keys (for specs which are created using `clojure.spec.alpha/keys`) using a spec's form/description"
  [fspec]
  (let [keymap (into {} (map (fn [pair] (vec pair)) (partition 2 (rest fspec))))]
    (->> (cond-> {}
           (contains? keymap :opt)
             (assoc :req (vec (concat (keymap :req) (keymap :opt))))
           (contains? keymap :opt-un)
             (assoc :req-un (vec (concat (keymap :req-un) (keymap :opt-un)))))
         (mapcat identity)
         (cons 'clojure.spec.alpha/keys))))

(clojure.spec.alpha/def ::name string?)
(clojure.spec.alpha/def ::desc string?)
(clojure.spec.alpha/def ::book (clojure.spec.alpha/keys :req [::name] :opt [:desc]))

(clojure.spec.gen.alpha/generate (clojure.spec.alpha/gen (eval (merge-opt-keys (clojure.spec.alpha/form ::book)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the short answer to your question is "no" but you could `s/merge` your spec with one that requires the optional keys:

```
(s/def ::name string?)
(s/def ::age pos-int?)
(s/def ::person (s/keys :req [::name] :opt [::age]))

(gen/sample (s/gen ::person)) ;; ::age not always gen'd
(gen/sample                   ;; ::age always gen'd
  (s/gen (s/merge ::person (s/keys :req [::age]))))
```

And you could write a macro that generates a `s/keys` spec w/generator that does this.